# When I render a pdf from quarto, all the figures are out of place in the document

Tags: r, pdf, quarto

The HTML render works correctly, with all figures rendered between text sections, as I have written the .qmd file. For some reason the pdf render puts the figures in different places in the text, with most of them all put together at the end of the document. I am not sure whether I need to change the YAML to stop this? They are in the correct order, but the wrong places in the text.

Current YAML:

```
title: "my doc title"
author: "my name"
date: last-modified
date-format: iso
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
format: 
  pdf: 
    number-sections: true
```

Thanks

Comment: Rendering to PDF goes through LaTeX which has a _completely_ different method for layout of tables and graphs. Look up "latex table placement" and you'll see some long discussions about it.

Answer (score 4):

Using fig-pos:"H" in the yaml solved it for me - using "h" did not help in my  case.

```
---
format: 
  pdf: 
    fig-pos: "H"
---
```

Check out the info box at the end of this section in the quarto docs: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#figure-position

In my case, because I globally set `echo: false`, text and figures were aligned using default latex settings and not in the order they were written.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the placement of a figure using the [`fig-pos`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#figures) argument:

````
---
format:
  pdf:
    fig-pos: 'h'
---

# Option 1

![](figure.png){fig.pos='h'}


# Option 2

```{r}
#| fig-pos: "t"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point()
```

# Option 3

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{figure.png}
\end{figure}
````

Concerning placement options you can see them [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables#Positioning_tables), e.g.

- `h` Place the float **here**, i.e., approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot)
- `t` Position at the **top** of the page
- ....

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no change to where the figures are placed. From what you say, it could be because they are large (long) figures.

Comment: without any reproducible examples it is very difficult to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a **\newline** after the image helps *pin* it for me. I got this from another SO post talking about Rmd but it translates to Quarto (I can't find the link to reference it here, unfortunately).

E.g.

`![Gradient](grad.jpg) \newline`

Comment: This is admittedly a bit more of a hack-y answer when there are good native Quarto ways to fix this issue like other answers have provided